# Console.log vs document.write

Tags: javascript, html, console.log, document.write

When using JavaScript in HTML, `console.log();` is replaced with `document.write();`. But `console.log();` is still perfectly usable, but I don't exactly know when it would be used, seeing as it doesn't print anything. And no site I've visited has had any real information about this.

`document.write("Thanks!!");`

Comment: Open your browser's Javascript console to see `console.log` in action. And `document.write` is hardly ever something useful to use. You'd rather manipulate the DOM with somewhat more complex but fitting methods.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen `document.write` used in any serious code. It's only ever been used as a debugging tool to output some information. And even then, mostly in examples simply because it's easy to draw on a page in an iframe or something. `console.log` is always more convenient, since it doesn't randomly modify your page and probably break formatting when you simply want to see what the value of something is.

Comment: *"console.log vs document.write"* `console.log`, definitely, Always `console.log` ;) the console can not just log multiple arguments, but it can also log every type of value, not just strings. check this `console.log(window)` and then press on the little triangle

Comment: have you read this..https://stackoverflow.com/a/35683033/7035903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log` logs to the `console`. If you use Chrome, press F12 and find it there. `document.write` writes to the document, i.e. to your HTML page. `document.write` is almost never used nowadays, because it replaces the whole page with what you write, and this is not much useful.

Answer (score 0):

This string will be placed on the website.

`document.write("Thanks!!");`

This string will be placed in the browser console (pres F12 to toggle console)

`console.log("Thanks!!");`

```js
document.write("Thanks!!");
console.log("Thanks!!");
```

Answer (score 0):

console.log is used to write logs to the console, mainly for debugging purposes
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log

document.write is used to write markup to the document, and if executed after page load it replaces everything in the header and body tag with the markup given to the method. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Answer (score 0):

I think you are new to Java Script.
`console.log()` is used to for debugging purpose.
While `document.write()` is used when you want some thing to be written on DOM of browser.