# Why is `alert(menu)` displaying `[object Object]` whereas `console.log(menu)` displays it just fine?

Tags: javascript

At the end of the code, when I do `alert(menu);`, I get `[object Object]`.
But when I do `console.log(menu);`, I get `{ width: 400, height: 600, title: 'My menu' }`, which is what I wanted. What’s causing the difference?

```js
let menu = {
  width: 200,
  height: 300,
  title: "My menu"
};

function multiplyNumeric(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[key] == "number") {
      obj[key] *= 2;
    }
  }
}

multiplyNumeric(menu);
alert(menu);
console.log(menu)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [difference between console.log / document.write and alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35682997/difference-between-console-log-document-write-and-alert)

Answer (score 3):

That is because `menu` itself is an Object.

When we use alert, a pop up box opens with a given message, which expects a String. When passed with an Object, you will instead get `[object Object]`

Try `alert(JSON.stringify(menu))` instead to see the full stringified output

Answer (score 1):

If you read properly on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_alert.asp). Alert takes string as parameter and your menu isn't a string it's object so instead of showing menu it shows the **type of menu**

you can do something like this :

```
alert(JSON.stringify(menu));
```